# What are other examples of characteristic numbers?

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

Be warned, this may be a ridiculous question.

I understand characteristic classes of principal $G$-bundles (and associated vector bundles) over a space $X$ arise from the classifying maps $f\colon X \to BG$ of those bundles by pulling back classes in $H^k(BG;R)$ along $f$, for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and coefficient ring $R$. For example, the Chern classes $c_k$ pull back from $H^{2k}(BU(n);\mathbb{Z})$ for big enough $n$, or from the colimit $H^*(BU;\mathbb{Z})$.

If $X$ is an $n$-manifold, then taking a cup product, with total degree $n$, of characteristic classes of the tangent bundle $TX$, and then evaluating it against the fundamental class, one gets a **characteristic number** of the manifold.

I know Pontrjagin numbers, Chern numbers, Stiefel–Whitney numbers, and the Euler characteristic arise in this way. But there are more characteristic classes I've seen named (although I couldn't tell you off the top of my head what $H^*(BG;R)$ they come from, and some I've never seen described that way; that would be nice to see too).

But it seems like there should be more characteristic numbers—there are after all more $G$ than $O(n)$ and $U(n)$ and more $R$ than $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Or maybe I'm just embarrassing myself on the internet.

**What are some other characteristic numbers?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say "characteristic number of a manifold" instead of "characteristic class of a principal $G$-bundle" you're gliding over some important points. First, your manifold needs to be closed and oriented for it to have a fundamental class. Second, a priori the tangent bundle of an $n$-dimensional manifold only gives you a principal $O(n)$-bundle (up to homotopy), and in order to get a principal $G$-bundle out of this for $G$ some other interesting group you need to supply some extra data, usually a choice of [reduction of the structure group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_the_structure_group) from $O(n)$ to $G$, which also requires specifying a morphism $G \to O(n)$. In particular, you can't talk about the Chern numbers of a $2n$-manifold until you pick an almost complex structure on it, or equivalently a reduction of the structure group from $O(2n)$ to $U(n)$.

It's also worth pointing out that the classical cases of characteristic numbers you describe happen to be particularly important: they are complete [cobordism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism) invariants (for oriented and complex cobordism respectively depending on the characteristic number).

So, having said that, here's an example that depends on a choice of principal $G$-bundle. Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\alpha$ be a class in $H^n(BG, U(1))$ where $U(1)$ has the discrete topology. If $M$ is a closed oriented $n$-manifold, then associated to the classifying map $f : M \to BG$ of any principal $G$-bundle on $M$ there is a characteristic number $f^{\ast}(\alpha) [M]$ called the [Dijkgraaf-Witten invariant](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dijkgraaf-Witten+theory) of $f$. This construction is important in producing a [topological quantum field theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+quantum+field+theory) called Dijkgraaf-Witten theory; the next step is to integrate the characteristic numbers above over the space of all principal $G$-bundles on $M$ in a suitable sense.

Comment: Thanks! It's really interesting that these characteristic numbers exist.

Comment: What role does the topology on $U(1)$ play here? I don't normally use topological structure on the coefficient group, so I'm not sure what role this assumption plays.

Comment: What sort of things does one learn from these invariants? Does one have to go to something as complicated as a space of all principal $G$-bundles to define other characteristic numbers?

Comment: @jdc: the discrete topology is used to ensure that the pullback $f^{\ast}(\alpha)$ has a chance to pair nontrivially with the fundamental class. With the usual topology $H^n(M, U(1)) \cong H^{n+1}(M, \mathbb{Z})$ vanishes.

Comment: @jdc: the information encoded in Dijkgraaf-Witten theory is a bit subtle; when $\alpha = 0$ you learn the number of homomorphisms from $\pi_1(M)$ into $G$ and when $\alpha \neq 0$ you learn a twisted version of this. But I think at least some people think of Dijkgraaf-Witten theory not as interesting in its own sake but as a toy model for, say, Chern-Simons theory; at least I think that's how it was originally introduced.

Comment: @jdc: to define other characteristic numbers all you really have to do is pick interesting maps $B \to BO(n)$ and ask for lifts of the classifying map of the tangent bundle through them (up to homotopy), then look at the cohomology of $B$ and see what happens. Usually $B = BG$ for some Lie group $G$ but other options are possible; the keyword here is "tangential structure." For example, after lifting through the sequence $B \text{String}(n) \to B \text{Spin}(n) \to BSO(n) \to BO(n)$ you get a string structure, and I think at this point you get new characteristic classes.

Comment: @jdc: already lifting to $B \text{Spin}(n)$ (a spin structure) is interesting; at this point you can equip your manifold with a fundamental class taking values not in homology but in KO-theory. You can evaluate this fundamental class against KO-versions of the Pontryagin classes to get characteristic numbers that, together with the usual Stiefel-Whitney classes, determine the class of a manifold in spin bordism (http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Spin_bordism).

Comment: This is all interesting. Thank you! For the $U(1)$-topology, I think I'm unfortunately asking a simpler question than the one you've answered. In the isomorphism $H^n(M;U(1)) \cong H^{n+1}(M;\mathbb Z)$, how is the cohomology group on the left defined to make this true? Are the cochains required to be continuous functions from the free abelian group on the singular simplicial complex to $U(1)$? Is the isomorphism somehow tied to $U(1)$ being $B\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @jdc: yes, it's all about $U(1)$ being $B\mathbb{Z}$. My preferred interpretation is that the LHS is $[M, B^n U(1)]$ where $B^n$ refers to the $n$-fold delooping. I don't know off the top of my head whether there's a nice chainy description.

Comment: The isomorphism would certainly follow from that. My usual interpretation of (singular) cohomology is as the homology of the singular cochain complex; is there an obvious intuitive reason why that's the same as your preferred interpretation?

Comment: @jdc: you mean with discrete coefficients? There's an unsatisfying proof involving the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. More directly I think the conceptual point is the Dold-Kan theorem.

Comment: Yes, I guess I've always used discrete coefficients without really thinking about it.

Also, I was familiar with the material in the first two paragraphs of your answer--and I'm sorry for being imprecise--until "up to homotopy"; are you referring to obtaining an $O(n)$-bundle structure from a $GL(n,\mathbb R)$-structure by deformation-retracting the latter group to the former? The construction I've seen assumes the manifold is smooth and finds a Riemannian metric. Is that assumption unnecessary?

Comment: @jdc: it's convenient, but yes, it's unnecessary. The point is that the natural map $BO(n) \to BGL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a homotopy equivalence, so up to homotopy specifying a classifying map into the latter is equivalent to specifying a classifying map into the former. More concretely this reflects the fact that the space of Riemannian metrics on a vector bundle is contractible.